# None Type issues in Python 2.6

Tags: python

I'm doing a script where I get some values from a Database but sometimes this value can be None, but when I assign it to a variable and try to compare it I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

I've already tried this:

```
if sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ][ 'name' ] != None:
    self.ui.brandComboBox_2.setEditText( sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ]['name' ] )

if not isinstanceof( sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ][ 'name' ], None ) != "":
    self.ui.brandComboBox_2.setEditText( sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ]['name' ] )

if sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ][ 'name' ] is not None:
    self.ui.brandComboBox_2.setEditText( sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ]['name' ] )

if type( sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ][ 'name' ]) is not type(None):
    self.ui.brandComboBox_2.setEditText( sgSlate[ 'sg_client_2' ]['name' ] )
```

and none of them worked.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unsubscriptable error arises when you try to perform a `[]` operation on a `None` variable. So in this case, it is most likely the `sgSlate['sg_client_2']` value that is `None`, not the `sgSlate['sg_client_2']['name']` itself.

Comment: Ok, that does it. No more voting up until it's April 2 in all time zones, I'm tired of these silly unicorns :)